# How to route dynamic sub-domains in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, subdomain, zend-route

I have problem with 'dynamic subdomains' on zend_router_hostname, i have code like(i don't have subdomains like that but whant use subdomain as route parametr):

```
protected function _initRoutes() {
        $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $router = $front->getRouter();
        $config = $this->getOptions();
        Zend_Registry::set("config", $config);
        $routerHost = new Zend_Controller_Router_Hostname(':language.mysite.local',
                        array('controller' => 'index',
                            'action' => 'index',
                            'language'=>'pl')
);
        $router->addDefaultRoutes();
        $routes = $router->getRoutes();
        foreach ($routes as $key => $routeEntry) {
            $router->addRoute($key, $routeHost->chain($routeEntry));
        }
    }
```

But when I try do call eg.: pl.mysite.local i get Server not found error.
My /etc/hosts file is:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.2.1       mysite.local
127.0.3.1       mysite.dev
127.0.4.1       mysite.production
```

And my vhost config is:

```
VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/mysite/public"
   ServerName mysite.local
   ServerAlias *.mysite.local
   # This should be omitted in the production environment
   SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
   <Directory "/var/www/mysite/public">
       Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I tried to use dnsmasq with entry like:

```
address=/local/127.0.0.1
```

But problem still occurs, i dont know how to resolve this situation, any clue what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Don't make your application complex. Route subdomains within the server configuration first, then do standard routing in Zend Framework. Your application will say thank you to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding wildcards to /etc/hosts is not possible but, also required in our case.
However, this is how to go about it:

Install [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html)

then,

```
cp /usr/share/doc/dnsmasq-base/examples/dnsmasq.conf.example /usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf
```

then, edit your /usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf and add:

```
address=/mysite.local/127.0.0.1
listen-address=127.0.0.1
```

Start DNSMASQ:

```
~$ sudo ./usr/local/sbin/dnsmasq
```

Further, instead of using Zend_Controller_Router_Hostname use [Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.hostname)

Go through the document and you should be OK!

```
$toRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname(
    ':language.mysite.local',
    array(
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'index',
        'language' => 'pl')
    ) );
```

PS: Don't forget to mention nameserver as 127.0.0.1 in /etc/resolv.conf . At times, restarting system helps!

Enjoy coding! :)

Comment: I get it, the problem is that whatever you define in routers is checked as a 'suffix' to your base domain. example: :xyz/yes will be example.com/xyz/{value}/yes and since you have used dot, it should give you an error too! anyways, let me check. However, host file is correctly set now, wait for router script.

Comment: @Axxxon I have edited the post. Check for the correct function to use (link provided). Also, tick it correct, if it works, if it doesn't then, let me know what came up!

Comment: i have changed it as You suggested @KarmicDice, now when trying to get to mysite.local i got redirect to www.mysite.local but problem with subdomains still occurs.

Comment: By any chance is your htaccess causing conflict? Redirected to www *eh?* that is strange! You added the route? I presume you did! Ok, what about your controller, it is fetching getParam(pl), isnt it?

Comment: @Axxxon Whew! Finally got the solution after long coffee sips :D /etc/hosts wildcards != work. So, put your /etc/hosts to as it was. and Follow the solution, as shown above. If still it doesn't, come back and mention it. :)

Comment: i edited /etc/hosts like You suggested @KarmicDice, changed dnsmasq config, used code in my Bootstrap.php as mentioned, and checked /etc/resolv.conf but now dynamic-subdomains don't work and while calling mysite.local i get No route matched the request error

Comment: is it normal that after adding 127.0.0.1 pl.mysite.local to /etc/hosts i got server response but problem with routes still occurs?

Comment: adding subdomain.hostname on /etc/hosts is not the solution. You need to configure DNS wildcard which we do using dnsmasq. I will get back on this on Monday :) Enjoy ur weekend!